# NSURLRequest memory size for cache in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlcache

Is the memorySize you specify for the cache (memory) mapped to the disk or is it real memory that is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memoryCapacity` specifies the size of the in-memory cache. It is not mapped to disk, it is real memory.

`diskCapacity` specifies the size of the on-disk cache - [on iOS 5 and later.](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2012/nsurlcache-uses-a-disk-cache-as-of-ios5/)

Answer (score 0):

IT is the cache (memory) mapped to the disk .not the real memory.

Comment: Then so is the disk capacity you specify?